# How to replicate array elements in C?

Tags: c

My code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{

    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("newindex.dat.txt", "r");

    float n1[12];
    float n2[12];
    float n3[12];
    float p[36];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        fscanf(myFile, "%f %f %f", &n1[i], &n2[i], &n3[i]);
    }

}  

0.0 0.0 1.20
1.0 0.0 1.20
2.0 0.0 1.20
3.0 0.0 1.20
0.0 1.0 1.40
1.0 1.0 1.40
2.0 1.0 1.42
3.0 1.0 1.48
0.0 2.0 1.50
1.0 2.0 1.50
2.0 2.0 1.52
3.0 2.0 1.54
```

I need to replicate third column elements three times,like this.

```
1.20
1.20
1.20
...
...
1.54
1.54
1.54
```

How to do that?

Comment: By "replicate third column elements three times" do you mean `0.0 0.0 1.20  0.0 0.0 1.20   0.0 0.0 1.20` or `0.0 0.0 1.20 1.20 1.20`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by replicate third column elements three times?

Comment: @hhyder Every element to appear three times, 1.20 1.20 1.20 and so on

Comment: @Bob__ No, 1.20 1.20 1.20 .... 1.54 1.54 1.54 ,36 alltogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put each element of the third column in array p replicated 3 times you can do this:

```
for (i = 0, k = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    fscanf(myFile, "%f %f %f", &n1[i], &n2[i], &n3[i]);
    p[k++] = n3[i];
    p[k++] = n3[i];
    p[k++] = n3[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since , the question doesn't seem quite clear , I assume you want n3 array to be in p[] array and it is to be repeated three times . 
You can easily do this by editing the for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        fscanf(myFile, "%f %f %f", &n1[i], &n2[i], &n3[i]);
        p[i]=p[i+12]=p[i+24]=n3[i];
    }
```

If my interpretation of your question is wrong , you may get an idea how to do that i.e. p[i] , p[i+number_of_elements] ,p[i =2* number_of_elements] are to be kept same.

Comment: No,take a look at my edit.

Comment: int k=0;for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        fscanf(myFile, "%f %f %f", &n1[i], &n2[i], &n3[i]);
        p[k++]=n3[i];p[k++]=n3[i];p[k++]=n3[i];
    }